# How to use Nuget install packages + VS TransformXML?

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, nuget, package, app-config

Most of the solutions talk about nuget packaging in applying transforms which target specific files which is why things like binding redirects will appear in a Web.Config or App.Config file.  However there doesn't seem to be a way to redirect of if using XMLTransform will loose these changes entirely.  Here is the scenario:

app.base.config - All common and default configuration

app.debug.config - overrides and configuration for debug build of app
app.production.config - overrides with production values
....

app.config - Final transform, and where nuget packages like to place their binding redirects

The transform in .csproj for building looks like this:

so the nuget installed bits are lost.

Can the nuget installation be redirected to app.base.config?

Can Add-BindingRedirect or other nuget command be part of the build to reapply overwiten changes?

Answer (score 1):

> Can the nuget installation be redirected to app.base.config?

Yes, the XDT feature can be apply to a**ny XML files**. You could use **app.base.config.(un)install.xdt** file to add transform content into app.base.config file directly.

More introduce for XDT in NuGet, please refer to following blog.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/24/how-to-use-xdt-in-nuget-examples-and-facts/

> Can Add-BindingRedirect or other nuget command be part of the build to
>   reapply overwiten changes?

The Add-BindingRedirect command is used to examine all assemblies within the output path for a project and adds binding redirects to the app.config or web.config where necessary. It is a PowerShell command for NuGet. So it is not a part of build to reapply overwriten changes. And I don't find any other command could reapply overwriten changes.

I suggest you use the XDT in Nuget to transform the binding redirect information in app.config file.

Comment: Is the XDT feature something as a consumer of a nuget package that can configure?  From the post you provided and other sources seem to pertain to the packaging itself targeting a config file and not likely for any nuget package's installs to target unexpected config files like app.base.config.